# Launch alerts from Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a Chrome extension for Twitter where I want to show an additional button on every tweet. I have managed to get the button to show, but now I want to launch an alert every time the user clicks on it. I'm unable to get it to work.
Just after adding the button to the DOM, I'm doing this in contentScript.js:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({message: "alertClick"}, function(response) {});
```

And I catch the event in background.js using the following:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.message == 'alertClick') {
         alert("Hello world!")
    }
```

However, when I launch Twitter, I get multiple alerts on launch. Nothing happens when I click my button though. I'm new to making Chrome extensions, so I may have missed several steps along the way. Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: You need to add a `click` event handler to your button and move your sendMessage code inside. Look for examples.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to figure it out. Adding an event listener to the buttons was all that was required.